# Lisp graph data structures

Tags: data-structures, common-lisp

I'm reading [Jorge Gajon's *Trees as Linked Lists in Common Lisp*](https://gajon.org/trees-linked-lists-common-lisp), which includes a description of a tree done in Lisp. The author gives this basic example:

[image]

Then gives a Lisp list representaton:

```
(1 (2 6 7 8) 3 (4 (9 12)) (5 10 11))
```

where position implies hierarchy level: 1 is first in the list, i.e., it's at the top, 2 is at the next level, but it's the top of its level, etc. But then he gives this caveat:

> PLEASE NOTE, that if you need to represent trees in a production program you shouldn’t use lists as described here unless you have a good reason. This is only an exercise in understanding how cons cells work.

All right, how should one represent the tree data structure in "production" code? BTW, I'd also like to see an example of an acyclic directed graph, i.e., something tree-like that also has "multiple parent" capabilities. For example in the diagram above, 8 is a child of 2, but also 3. I'm guessing something like this:

```
(1 (2 6 7 8) (3 8) (4 (9 12)) (5 10 11))
```

but it seems like I've created a "shadow" twin of 8 and not really relating how the 8 that is the child of 3 is the same 8 that also has 2 as a parent. This problem gets worse if I wanted to have 3 as 12's parent.

```
(1 (2 6 7 8) (3 8 12) (4 (9 12)) (5 10 11))
```

The fact that 12 is in a lower hierarchy gets lost in the shuffle, so to speak.

Is there a good and proper treatment (book, etc.) of data structures in the Lisp/Scheme/Clojure world? I've only found one-off stuff like this.

Comment: By the way, the problem with defining trees this way is that there is no way to tell the difference between conses that are *part of* the tree and conses that are *in* the tree as elements. The way to fix that is to define data structures (with `defstruct` or `defclass`) to contain the elements and tree structure in separate slots, removing any need to distinguish them.

Comment: If your use case is opportune, you can also do this in production code. For example, if you know, that it is just a small hand full of nodes. I say this in the same sense as if someone recommended to use a hyper-super-modern-multi-core sort algorithm to sort a set of 2 items...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'production' code would use CLOS (the Common Lisp Object System) to define a `NODE` class and operations over the graph/tree.

Comment: Any definitive "A&DS" books for the Lisp language family?

Comment: @LawrenceBottorff: you can adapt most 'Algorithms and Data Structure' books easily to Lisp. Procedures, Records, Arrays, ... are all available in Lisp. Special language editions for Lisp are unusual, because the market is small and most Lisp programmers have no problem reading C, Java or Pascal examples.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have quicklisp installed, and you should, then consider the libaries enumerated by: (ql:system-apropos "graph"), and also try cliki http://cliki.net/site/search?query=graph