# Representing a directed acyclic graph in Common Lisp

Tags: graph, lisp, common-lisp, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

Normally, to represent a basic undirected graph in Lisp, I can create a list of parent nodes and their corresponding children nodes, as was discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724226/lisp-graph-data-structures) (illustrated below for convenience).

[image]

this graph yields a list of edges:

```
(1 (2 6 7 8) 3 (4 (9 12)) 5 (10 11))
```

This works in the case of a tree or any other undirected graph. However, this type of representation breaks down when we want to represent a directed acyclic graph where each node can have multiple parents:

[image]

Now, Node 8 has multiple parents (2, 3), but when we attempt to represent this, we lose the ability to tell if node 8 is connected to two parent nodes, or if there are two node 8's:

```
(1 (2 6 7 8) (3 8) (4 (9 12)) (5 10 11))
```

In the case of a graph with unique nodes, we certainly can make this assumption, but to my knowledge, DAGs can have duplicate nodes ... so how do we deal with this? Further, how do we represent it as a list in Lisp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right way to represent a DAG is a collection of *nodes* (vertices):

```
(defstruct node
  payload
  children)
```

Since the struct has just two slots, one can use, of course,
[`cons`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_cons.htm) cells instead.

The list representation of the tree you give
conflates *payload* with a childless *node*
and messes up the rightmost branch.
The correct representation is

```
(1 (2 (6) (7) (8)) (3) (4 (9 (12))) (5 (10) (11)))
```

Now, the DAG that shares the childless node `(8)` between the children
of nodes `(2 ...)` and `(3 ...)` should merely share the cell:

```
(1 (2 (6) (7) #1=(8)) (3 #1#) (4 (9 (12))) (5 (10) (11)))
```

See [`#n=`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dho.htm) and
[`#n#`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dhp.htm) for the reader notation.
Of course, you should not use them to *create* DAGs.

Here is how one would create the DAG:

```
(defun make-node (&key payload children)
  (cons payload children))
(defparameter *my-dag*
  (let ((shared-mode (make-node :payload 8)))
    (make-node
     :payload 1
     :children
     (list (make-node :payload 2
                      :children (list (make-node :payload 6)
                                      (make-node :payload 7)
                                      shared-mode))
           (make-node :payload 3
                      :children (list shared-mode))
           (make-node :payload 4
                      :children (list (make-node :payload 9
                                                 :children (list (make-node :payload 12)))))
           (make-node :payload 5
                      :children (list (make-node :payload 10)
                                      (make-node :payload 11)))))))
(setq *print-circle* t)
*my-dag*
==> (1 (2 (6) (7) #1=(8)) (3 #1#) (4 (9 (12))) (5 (10) (11)))
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like exactly what I was looking for. Is this effectively assigning a reference to the same 8 node? Does it matter what integer value I use for #n=? Or is that simply a reference value?

Comment: You should not use the `#n=` notation yourself, you should construct your graph by creating nodes and populating them with children and payloads.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just list the vertices with both node ids:

```
((1 2) (1 3) (1 4) (1 5) (2 6) (2 7) (2 8) ... )
```

or use a vector:

```
#((1 2) (1 3) (1 4) (1 5) (2 6) (2 7) (2 8) ... )
```

or use a list of nodes with their successors:

```
((1 2 3 4 5) (2 6 7 8) (3 8) (4 9) ...)
```

Comment: Using this notation, if the graph contains duplicates, how can I be sure that (2 6 7 8) and (3 8) are in fact pointing to the same 8 node?

Comment: @ChristianAbbott: two ways: a) use the nodes themselves, b) use node IDs